# Getting linker error

Tags: visual-c++

I am tring singalton class example.
here is the .h file

```
#ifndef __SINGALTON_CLASS__
#define __SINGALTON_CLASS__

#include "iostream"

class CConfig
{
private:
    CConfig(){};

private:
    bool status;
    static CConfig* config;

public:
    static CConfig* initilize_config();
    ~CConfig()
    {
    }
    void displayStatus()
    {
        std::cout << "Status:"<<status;
    }
};

#endif //__SINGALTON_CLASS__
```

and here is the .cpp file code..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SingaltonClass.h"

void hello();

CConfig* 
CConfig :: initilize_config()
{
    if (config == 0)
    {
        config = new CConfig();
    }
    return config;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CConfig *cconfig = CConfig::initilize_config();
    cconfig->displayStatus();

    hello();
    return 0;
}

void hello()
{
    CConfig *config = CConfig::initilize_config();
    config->displayStatus();
}
```

on compiling on visual studio 10 i am getting following error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class CConfig * CConfig::config" (?config@CConfig@@2PAV1@A)
SingaltonClass.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

i am not able to understand where is the problem exactly..
please reply..

Answer (score 1):

You declared a static member in your header, but you didn't define it:

```
class CConfig
{
    // ... blah blah ...
private:
    static CConfig* config;

    // ... blah blah ...
};
```

You also need to define a variable for it in your cpp file:

```
CConfig* CConfig::config = NULL;
```

Quoting [from here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/class.html):

> **9.4.2  Static data members**
>   The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is
>   not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than 
>   cv-qualified   void.   The  definition  for  a  static  data member
>   shall appear in a   namespace scope enclosing the member's class
>   definition.  In the defi-   nition at namespace scope, the name of the
>   static data member shall be   qualified by its class name using the ::
>   operator.   The  initializer   expression  in  the definition of a
>   static data member is in the scope   of its class
>   (*basic.scope.class*).

Comment: I initialized that variable but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: @RavindraGupta Update your question with the new code, then. Your question still has source code with a  missing definition.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I have missing to defining the static variable outside of class.
SO here in the header file itself I add one line at the last and it's works..

```
 CConfig* CConfig::config;
```